# dataTable duplicate record's on liveScroll

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a dataTable and after updating a record with dialog and executing the position script the records are duplicated.

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl" 
        value="#{fincaBean.listFinca}" var="f" 
        emptyMessage="sin registros" 
        selection="#{fincaBean.slcFinca}" 
        selectionMode="single" 
        rowKey="#{f.finid}"
        filteredValue="#{fincaBean.filtroFinca}"
        scrollRows="20"
        liveScroll="true"
         scrollable="true" 
        scrollHeight="350">
.....
<p:commandButton onstart="saveScrollPos()"  oncomplete="PF('finDialog').show()" actionListener="#{fincaBean.actualizarFinca(f) }" update=":updateFinca" process="@this"  icon="ui-icon-search" title="Detalle">
....
....
</dataTable>
//*************************************************************//
<p:dialog id="detalleFin" style="max-width:800px;max-height:380px" 
        height="80vh" width="98%"  position="center" header="Detalle Finca" 
        widgetVar="finDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" 
        hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
....
....
<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#fincaBean.guardarFinca(fincaBean.finca)}" oncomplete="getScrollPos()"  update="@form :formFinca:tbl" process="@all">
</p:dialog>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $ = jQuery;
            var scrollPos;

            function saveScrollPos() {
                        scrollPos = $(".ui-datatable-scrollable-body").scrollTop();
            }
            function getScrollPos() {
                    $(".ui-datatable-scrollable-body").scrollTop(scrollPos);
            }
    </script>
```

image-->  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fKv6.jpg

Comment: `$ = jQuery;` - why are you doing this, was something else assigned to `$` before? PrimeFaces expects `$` to be jQuery.

Comment: i dont know jquery, the code is copy of other solution.
the only thing I want is to position myself in the selected registry after updating in the dialog.
update = "form: datatable" refreshes the datatable and the focus of the selected record is lost.